# ede-proj-regenerate does weird things with my Makefile

Tags: emacs, makefile, cedet

I have created a really basic project (Make) like this:

```
(ede-proj-project "zrm"
  :name "zrm"
  :file "Project.ede"
  :targets (list
   (ede-proj-target-makefile-program "zm"
    :name "zrm"
    :path ""
    :source '("zrm.c")
    )
   )
  )
```

When doing `M-x ede-proj-regenerate RET` and `M-x compile RET RET` (accepting make -k as my compile command), make keeps bailing with a **missing separator error.

When editing my Makefile outside of Emacs (with the darn evil vi) and replacing spaces by tabs, it works.

Is there anything special I should pay attention in order to have this work ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after several hours of struggle, I have found the culprit. I had a hook on `before-save-hook` which did `untabify` for several modes. There was a bug there. I fixed it and now it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

If you hand-wrote that project file, you need to know that this isn't necessary.

Just use:

```
M-x ede-new RET
```

to create a new project, and then use the menu to add new targets, or use

```
M-x ede-new-target RET
```

to do so.

If your project is multiple directories, you will need to do an `ede-new` for each one, and EDE will connect them by proximity.